# Size cannot resloved to be a type

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc

I got this error when try to validate my form..This is my corresponding class file

```
    public class MyUser {

    @NotNull

    @Size(min=1,max=20)
    private String name;

    @Min(0)
    @Max(120)

    private int age;

    public MyUser(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public MyUser() {
        name = "";
        age = 0;
    }

}
```

*Here i also added the Corresponding javax.validation jar file in my class path but i still got this error.Can anyone give me any suggestions.*

Comment: Have you imported `javax.validation.constraints.Size`?

Comment: ya i imported javax.validation.*; in my class

Comment: You have to import `javax.validation.constraints.*` too.

Comment: yes buddy it is cleared now.i guessed that will ok but thx for your time

Comment: yes Jens i didnt import that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import `javax.validation.constraints.*` or  `javax.validation.constraints.Size`